# How does .Net 6 determine its Enviroment

Tags: console-application, .net-6.0, environment

I've created a .Net 6.0 Console application. I need it to be able to migrate the database using Entity Framework. Now when I run it, it says its environment is 'Production'. Where is that configured?

[image]

Here's the startup code for the application.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseSerilog((context, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration)
                .WriteTo.Console())
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
            {
                services.RegisterCoreServices(context.Configuration);
            })
            .Build();

        CallBatch(host.Services, args);

        host.RunAsync();
    }
```

Comment: check for environment variable "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT". it must be set to production somewhere either inside the projcet settings, launchSettings.json or your machine itself.

Comment: [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Production is the default.

Check out [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

> **Environments**
>
> To determine the runtime environment, ASP.NET Core reads from the following environment variables:
>
> 1. DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT
> 2. ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT when the WebApplication.CreateBuilder method is called. The default ASP.NET Core web app templates call WebApplication.CreateBuilder. The ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT value overrides DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT.
>
> IHostEnvironment.EnvironmentName can be set to any value, but the following values are provided by the framework:
>
> 1. Development: The launchSettings.json file sets ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development on the local machine.
> 2. Staging
> 3. Production: The default if DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT and ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT have not been set.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution. The variable was not set at all and thus the default was taken.